# How to retrieve variable from other sprite?

Tags: godot

I have a variable in sprite1:

`var answer = false`

I would like to transfer this same variable to sprite2 without having to redefine and for the variable in sprite2 to change when the variable in sprite1 changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming both of these sprites share a parent node at some level, you can use the observer pattern to update sprite2 any time sprite1 is modified.

First, let's set up a signal on `Sprite1`. The signal is only emitted when we call `update_answer`. That means we'll have to call it instead of setting `answer` directly.

*If you're familiar with getters and setters, you can use a setter instead. Otherwise this strategy works fine.*

```
// Sprite1
signal answer_changed(answer)
var answer = false

func update_answer(new_answer):
    answer = new_answer
    emit_signal("answer_changed", new_answer)
```

The parent should have a reference to both of the children. In `ready`, connect to `sprite1`'s signal. Now the parent will be listening for updates. Any time it receives a signal from `sprite1`, it will automatically `update_sprite2`.

```
// Parent
onready var sprite1 = $Sprite1
onready var sprite2 = $Sprite2

func _ready():
    sprite1.connect("answer_changed", self, "update_sprite2")

func update_sprite2(answer):
    sprite2.answer = answer
```